# mvnDebug tomcat7:run don't suspend

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, tomcat

I have a project which I run on local by

```
mvnDebug tomcat7:run
```

Now, I know that mvnDebug is equivalent to

```
MAVEN_DEBUG_OPTS=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=8000
```

Here, `suspend=y` and I want the `suspend=n`. Basically, with `suspend=y` , I have to start the remote debugger in between as the process halts for it. I dont want that. Hence, `suspend=n`.

So, I ran

```
mvn tomcat7:run -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000
```

But I am getting this error:

> [ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'runjdwp' in the current project
>   and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo]
>   available from the repositories...

Even if I run above command with `suspend=y` , still same error.

What should I do ?
I am running Java 8

Answer (score 0):

Just use `-Dexec.args` to pass your arguments to java rather than maven itself.
This should work

```
mvn tomcat7:run -Dexec.args="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000"
```

Comment: Nope. That did not work. `Error running '${Project_name}': Unable to open debugger port (localhost:8000): java.net.ConnectException "Connection refused (Connection refused)"`

Comment: So it did work - arguments were applied correctly. As I remember if port already occupied you should see different error. Might be something like firewall or transport rules block it.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, if I run `mvnDebug tomcat7:run` that works fine. So if  something like firewall or transport rules block it, even above wont run.

Comment: Sorry, initially I missed equals sign after -Dexec.args.